# Deploy "Azure App Services" App to other tenant

Tags: azure

We have made us a single-tenant AAD authenticated app for internal use with our O365. We deploy it directly from VisualStudio to Azure App Services.

A bunch of customers have seen that app and want to also use this app for their projects, so the boss decided we could possibly sell it to them (binary, no code) and create a new business opportunity that way.

It is single tenant and we don't want to go hosted, because otherwise we could access other companies' office documents, which means very much paperwork and even liability here in Germany.

Is there a possibility to easily "copy" the app into their Azure, or provide it via marketplace or some similar option? Given that we are adding features every month, an option that would allow easy update cycles would be prefered.

Comment: Are you talking about the physical files for the app? or the underlying AAD application configuration? How did you deploy the app in the first place?

Comment: We deployed the app into our Azure by firing up Visual Studio, loading the project, and clicking "Web Deploy". We would have to hand out the app's source code to other companies so they could do it the same way we did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Private Deployment**

1. Setup local publishing on Visual Studio
2. Publish to local folder `d:\project-name\deployment\web`
3. Setup Git for the project `d:\project-name\deployment\web` without any .gitignore file
4. For each client in your clients

   - Add remote (git end point of their Azure Web Site)
   - push your code (remember this one is only binary code)
   - Remove remote

You will have to combine powershell and some of git commands to make it work completely automatically.

**Public Deployment**

1. Setup local publishing on Visual Studio
2. Publish to local folder `d:\project-name\deployment\web`
3. Sync `d:\project-name\deployment\web` code to some public Git host like BitBucket and Github without any .gitignore file.
4. Any client can easily setup Azure Website with this git, however, this git will not have source code, but only dll,config and view files. You can then setup some sort of licensing in private web.config setup.